# Java map Collection<T> to Collection<U>

Tags: java, generics

I need to transform an arbitrary `Collection<T>` into another arbitrary `Collection<U>`. For example, I would like to transform an `ArrayList<String>` into a `HashSet<Integer>`.

I wrote the following code, which gives me a compile-time error on `UCollection::new` (Cannot resolve constructor 'UCollection'). I tried replacing it with `() -> new UCollection()`, which gives me another compile-time error (Type parameter 'UCollection' cannot be instantiated directly).

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Utils {
    public static <T, U, TCollection extends Collection<T>, UCollection extends Collection<U>>
    UCollection MappedCollection(TCollection collection, Function<T, U> function) {
        return MappedStream(collection.stream(), function).collect(Collectors.toCollection(UCollection::new));
    }

    public static <T, U> Stream<U> MappedStream(Stream<T> stream, Function<T, U> function) {
        return stream.map(function);
    }
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: You need to take what the Collectors.toCollection() method takes as argument: a Supplier<UCollection>. But really, your utility methods don't bring more to what stream.map().collect() natively brings. I would simply remove thes methods and use stream.map().collect() directly. BTW, they also disrespect the Java naming conventions.

Comment: @JBNizet Apologies, I'm coming from a C# background.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UCollection::new` is invalid because `UCollection` is a type variable. You can't construct a type that you don't know in the method.

The easiest fix here is to make your caller supply a `UCollection` factory:

```
public static <T, U, TCollection extends Collection<T>, 
                UCollection extends Collection<U>>
    UCollection MappedCollection(TCollection collection, 
                                 Function<T, U> function,
                                 Supplier<UCollection> uCollectionSupplier) {

    return MappedStream(collection.stream(), function)
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(uCollectionSupplier));
}
```

As a side note, I think you have one type variable too many. You could dispense with `TCollection` (using `C` for `UCollection` below)...

```
public static <T, U, C extends Collection<U>> 
    C mappedCollection(Collection<T> collection, 
                       Function<T, U> function,
                       Supplier<C> collectionSupplier) {
    return MappedStream(collection.stream(), function)
           .collect(Collectors.toCollection(collectionSupplier));
}
```

Comment: TCollection is useless, but not UCollection. This would force the caller to cast the return to, let's say, HashSet instead of simply using the generic return type.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest an output parameter instead of a result, as it allows *interface* based variables, already providing the correct implementation class. The other answer requires actually passing an `ArrayList::new` which is a bit unfortunately, though a result is more functional programming style.

```
public <P, R> void convert(Collection<P> cp, Collection<R> cr, Function<P, R> mapper) {
    cp.stream().map(mapper).forEach(cr::add);
}

    List<String> slist = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.addAll(slist, "2", "3", "5", "7", "5", "3");
    Set<Integer> iset = new HashSet<>();
    convert(slist, iset, Integer::valueOf);
    System.out.println(iset);
```

Stream aggregating and collecting often has such a new collection supplier as parameter as in the other answer. But where the resulting collection is created seems irrelevant. And a result sometimes requires type inference (no interface vars, or needing a cast).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a different, in my opinion more readable, solution:

```
public static <T, U> List<U> convert(Collection<T> collection, Function<T, U> mapper) {
    return collection.stream()
        .map(mapper)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2WWgE4)

If you really need to control the exact collection type, then use [ernest_k's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59684859/4216641) by passing a `Supplier<UCollection> supplier` to the method:

```
public static <T, U, UCollection extends Collection<U>> UCollection convert(
        Collection<T> collection,
        Function<T, U> mapper, 
        Supplier<UCollection> collectionSupplier) {
    return collection.stream()
        .map(mapper)
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(collectionSupplier));
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/gSup9I)

Comment: I don't want a list, I want the collection to be specified at the call site.

Comment: Then use the approach used by @ernest_k, by passing a `Supplier<UCollection>` to the function.

Comment: I updated my answer and added an example utilizing a `Supplier<UCollection>`.